# change css in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using angular for front end in my app and i want to be able change the CSS in my page according to the response angular gets from the server.
 For example, for a response like :

> {...
>     color: white,
>     background : blue,
>   ...
>   }

I want the my page (say index.html) to change background color to blue and text to white.

This is just an example and i want to change more CSS than just the background color.
How do i get about this?

Comment: Provide an example of what you have tried or at least some more details on what you are trying to accomplish,

Comment: you can achieve this with ng-style like this ng-style="{'background-color': data.backgroundCol}"

Comment: try ngStyle for body or append new <style></style> to header with server response

Comment: thanks!! ng-style is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: You should also be able to use simple JS or Jquery

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass and this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle
Find a way to set some way to bind this `ng-style` or `ng-class` attributes to scope variable from controller after you receive response from server.